Getting the file path in Android Studio from a pure Java-written jar file
I am currently developing two independent projects: an Android project and a pure Java module project. I intend to import the Java module into the Android project as a jar file. I want the jar file to retrieve a specific file path within the Android project on its own when the void test() function is executed without any parameters.
Is this possible?
Jar file location: app/src/main/assets/test.jar
Target file location : app/src/main/assets/target.jar
App main file location: app/src/main/java/myapp/MainActivity.kt
I tried using the code test.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() based on many resources, but the value is null and it does not work.


Is this possible?

No, because assets are not files on the device's filesystem. Like resources, they are entries in an APK file. You would need to make a copy of the asset to some file that you control, using AssetManager to get a stream on the asset.

I intend to import the Java module into the Android project as a jar file

I would describe what you are trying to do is dynamically load the JAR file. That will not work, if the JAR file is from "a pure Java module project", because Android does not use Java bytecode.
